# Preserve 3d Transform Style in MS Edge breaks Background Attachment Fixed

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

Just as the title says, when I have `transform-style:preserve-3d` enabled for an element, though every other browser has no problem with it, Microsoft Edge starts ignoring any `background-attachment:fixed` I have also applied to that element.

Is this documented behavior? A bug? Is there a known workaround?

EDIT: Here's a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYpYBr

In addition, as pointed out in the comments, this behavior doesn't seem to be specific to `transform-style`. It seems to happen with any type of CSS transform applied to the element.

Comment: I just encountered this. Along with `transform-style`, it seems that fixed backgrounds also do not work if you have a `transform` for the element or a parent.

Comment: Could you provide a small example? I work on the Edge team and will gladly file a bug if necessary.

Comment: @Sampson Of course. Here's a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYpYBr
Try removing the `transform` CSS line and notice how the background fixes properly.

Comment: @mt_xing Thanks, I'll take a look at this!

Comment: Was experiencing the same issue with the parent element having a transform(3d) applied, and after some messing around, I tried `transform:translate3d(0,0,0)` on the element with the background on it -seemed to sort it out :)

Comment: This issue still seems to exist in Firefox 122.0  
See my pen for it: https://codepen.io/axherrm/pen/YzgYEeL  

Anyone found a fix for that?